# Open an Excel Database ( libxls error: Unable to open file )

Tags: r, readxl

i'm trying to open an excel database on R, but I get this error

`library(readxl)`

`MRW <- read_excel("MRW.XLS")`

`View(MRW)`

**Error:**
**libxls error: Unable to open file**

How can I solve??
( The working directory is set fine )

Comment: Are you getting this error message after the call to `read_excel` or after the call to `View`?

Comment: See here <https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/598>